# Random variable notation in Gaussian Process

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variable, gaussian-process, notation

In a number of online articles (e.g. [1](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-gaussian-process-the-socratic-way-ba02369d804), [2](https://peterroelants.github.io/posts/gaussian-process-tutorial/)) I see the $x$ values over which a Gaussian Process is used written as $X$, e.g. the training points are $X$, test points are $X_*$, and (in the 1D case) the observed data or points to predict $Y = f(X)$.

However, my understanding is that we know the values of $x$ over which we have observed data and pre-define the $x$ values over which we want to predict $f(x)$. This makes me think $X$ is not a random variable, though of course $f(X)$ is.

Is it okay to write this these values with $x$ , $x_* $ and define $Y$ the random variable $Y = f(x), \ Y_* = f(x_*)$? This is clearer for me, but I don't want to have misunderstood something important.

Comment: your notation is appropriate for the deterministic case

Comment: Thanks John, could you elaborate on possible non-deterministic case for Gaussian processes?

Comment: oh in that case $f(x)$ is the "true" underlying function value (that we would get if we evaluated the function at $x$ many times and then averaged the output), while $Y=f(x)+\epsilon$ is the noisy observed function value.